# how to make Tabs Outliner, for Chromium Browser, popup on mouse move to screen edge?

Tags: chrome, dialog

So, we have the Tabs Outliner extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl

That is a very good vertical tabs manager for chromium.
The problem is it occupies too much screen, and I don't have a widescreen monitor.
So it is a new chrome window that would be visible all the time, occupying the left side of the screen.

The problem is: how make it hide automatically after you move your mouse away from it, and after you double click on one of its listed tabs?

Answer (score 2):

ok, I managed to code a script for that, you may find it usefull to provide similar functionality to other situations. If yo do so I would like to know too :)

Also if there is a better way to do that I would like to know too :)

the beggining variables are your options

```
#!/bin/bash -i

waitStart=5
delayRaiseTabOutliner=0.1
screenLeftMarginOpen=10
screenLeftMarginClose=200
bUseScreenLeftMarginClose=false
bGoToChromiumWhenTablinkIsDoubleClicked=true

function FUNCparent() {
    xwininfo -tree -id $1 |grep "Parent window id"
}
function FUNCparentest() {
    local check=`printf %d $1`
    local parent=-1
    local parentest=-1

    #echo "Child is: $check" >&2

    while ! FUNCparent $check |grep -q "(the root window)"; do
      #echo "a $check" >&2 #DEBUG info
        xwininfo -id $check |grep "Window id" >&2 #report
        parent=`FUNCparent $check |egrep -o "0x[^ ]* "`
        parent=`printf %d $parent`
        check=$parent
        sleep 1
    done
    if((parent!=-1));then
        parentest=$parent
    fi

    if((parentest!=-1));then
        echo $parentest
        #echo "Parentest is: $check" >&2
    else
        echo $1
        #echo "Child has no parent." >&2
    fi
}

while true; do
    list=(`xdotool search Chromium 2>/dev/null`)
    chromiumWindowId=""
    for windowId in `echo ${list[*]}`; do 
        if xwininfo -id $windowId |grep "Window id" |egrep -oq " - Chromium\"$"; then
            chromiumWindowId=$windowId
            xwininfo -id $chromiumWindowId |grep "Window id" #report
            break;
        fi
    done
    if [[ -z "$chromiumWindowId" ]]; then
        sleep $waitStart
        continue;
    fi

    list=(`xdotool search "Tabs Outliner" 2>/dev/null`)
    tabsOutlinerWindowId=""
    for windowId in `echo ${list[*]}`; do 
        if xwininfo -id $windowId |grep "Window id" |egrep -oq "\"Tabs Outliner\"$"; then
            tabsOutlinerWindowId=`FUNCparentest $windowId`
            xwininfo -id $tabsOutlinerWindowId |grep "Window id" #report
            break;
        fi
    done
    if [[ -z "$tabsOutlinerWindowId" ]]; then
        sleep $waitStart
        continue;
    fi

    previousWindowId=-1
    previousChromeTabName=""
    while true; do
        # check if chromium is still running
        if ! xdotool getwindowname $chromiumWindowId 2>&1 >/dev/null; then
            break;
        fi
        if ! xdotool getwindowname $tabsOutlinerWindowId 2>&1 >/dev/null; then
            break;
        fi

        # info about window below mouse (even if have not focus)
        eval `xdotool getmouselocation --shell 2>/dev/null`
        windowId=$WINDOW
        mouseX=$X
        mouseY=$Y

# not working yet...        
        # must work only if over chromium application windows
        #activeWindow=`xdotool getactivewindow`
        #activeWindow=`FUNCparentest $activeWindow`

        #echo "windowId=$windowId, chromiumWindowId=$chromiumWindowId, tabsOutlinerWindowId=$tabsOutlinerWindowId, previousWindowId=$previousWindowId, activeWindow=$activeWindow" #DEBUG info

# not working yet...        
        # only allowed to work if chromium windows has focus
#       if((activeWindow!=chromiumWindowId && activeWindow!=tabsOutlinerWindowId));then
#           sleep $delayRaiseTabOutliner
#           continue
#       fi
        #echo "Chromium app is active."

        # from chromium to tabs outliner!
        if((windowId==chromiumWindowId));then
            if((mouseX<screenLeftMarginOpen));then
                xdotool windowactivate $tabsOutlinerWindowId
                echo "activate TabOutliner (`date`)"
            fi
        fi

        # from tabs outliner to chromium
        bActivatedChromium=false
        # when a tabs outliner tab is double clicked, it changes chromium window current tab!
        if $bGoToChromiumWhenTablinkIsDoubleClicked; then
            if((windowId==tabsOutlinerWindowId));then
                currentChromeTabName=`xprop -id $chromiumWindowId |grep "^WM_NAME(STRING) = \""`
                if [[ -z "$previousChromeTabName" ]]; then
                    previousChromeTabName="$currentChromeTabName"
                fi
                if [[ "$currentChromeTabName" != "$previousChromeTabName" ]]; then
                    xdotool windowactivate $chromiumWindowId
                    bActivatedChromium=true
                fi
                previousChromeTabName="$currentChromeTabName"
            fi
        fi

        if $bUseScreenLeftMarginClose;then
            if((windowId==tabsOutlinerWindowId));then
                if((mouseX>screenLeftMarginClose));then
                    xdotool windowactivate $chromiumWindowId
                    bActivatedChromium=true
                fi
            fi
        else
            if((previousWindowId==tabsOutlinerWindowId));then
                if((windowId==chromiumWindowId));then
                    xdotool windowactivate $chromiumWindowId
                    bActivatedChromium=true
                fi
            fi
        fi

        if $bActivatedChromium; then
            echo "activate Chromium (`date`)"
        fi

        previousWindowId=$windowId

        sleep $delayRaiseTabOutliner
    done
done
```